# SQL Server 2008: How to use SQL to output XML from Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to declare a variable 'XMLOutput' and have it produce the contents of a table in XML format.  If you could provide a really simple example I could work off of I would really appreciate it.  I tried using the `xmlelement()` but could not get it to work.

Comment: for xml auto, Elements will put data into correct xml format for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server provides the ability to generate XML based on table structure via the [FOR XML clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx).  It's options are:

- RAW
- AUTO
- PATH
- EXPLICIT

There are examples for each in the link.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know an easy way to do the reverse? I need to import a large XML file (actually a SOAP file) and currently use a bloated SSIS structure for it...

Comment: @littlegreen: That's called "shredding" - [here's an article on it for SQL Server 2005](http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-6140404.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
FOR XML RAW
```

In the end of your query. This will return results as XML. Does that do what you want ? If not, I think you might need to elaborate your question a bit further. You could also have a look at [the documentation, to see what options you have with `FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx).

Comment: Select
 xmlelement(Loc, 'Loc', g.Loc)
from
 sitemap sm

for xml raw

Comment: Select top 5
 priority
from
 ghhsitemap g

for xml raw

this produces xml but in wrong format(<row priority='.9'/>, I just need <Priority>.9</priority>

Answer (score 0):

```
create xml schema collection cricketschemacollection
AS N'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLschema">
<xsd:element name="MatchDetails">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd::complexContent>
<xsd:restiriction base="xsd:anyType">
<xsd:sequences>
<xsd:element name="Team" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd::complexContent>
<xsd:restiriction base="xsd:anyType">
<xsd:sequences/>
<xsd:attribute name="country"type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="score"type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:restiriction>
</xsd::complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequences>
</xsd:restiriction>
</xsd::complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>'
```